# What is the best way to export functions from a LiveScript module?

Tags: javascript, optimization, livescript

with LiveScript, when you write some code in a file, the default compiler wraps the compiled code in an anonymous function :

Compiling this:

```
add10 = -> it + 10
```

gives that:

```
(function(){
  var add10;
  add10 = function(it){
    return it + 10;
  };
}).call(this);
```

And that is ok ! but i want to export some API functions for my module, so what i do now is this :

```
add10 = -> it + 10

this.add10 = add10
```

giving that :

```
(function(){
  var add10;
  add10 = function(it){
    return it + 10;
  };
  this.add10 = add10;
}).call(this);
```

I work in a browser context, and i wonder if there were no better solution. It actually works but i would rahter something like this:

```
(function(w){
  var add10;
  add10 = function(it){
    return it + 10;
  };
  w.add10 = add10;
}(this));
```

It's less code (no big difference in such a small example).

Comment: What's wrong with just adding a var w = this; before?

Comment: I don't know i'm looking for good practices tips !

Comment: If I understand correctly, you prefer the last example over the second to last because it's less code. But that doesn't matter if you use compression -- which you should, especially if the file is big enough that the difference between `w.` and `this.` becomes significant.

Comment: yeah i use compression. The real reason is that i'd rather avoid using of the this keyword

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say, use :

```
export add10 = (+ 10)
```

:).

Comment: the home page of Livescript does not mention this feature. I've already tried to search for 'export' on it but i didn't tried in code. I should have :)

Comment: I opened an issue for that already : https://github.com/gkz/LiveScript/issues/311